# Template function implicit/explicit parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use template function to do interpolation for pixel values.

I have two classes of interpolators that implements the interpolation algorithm.

```
class LinearInterpolator;
class NearestNeighborInterpolator;
```

I have different classes of images;

```
class ColorImage;
class GrayScaleImage;
```

I then have a function that does interpolation utilizing the specific interpolator you pick.

```
template<typename InterpType, typename ImageType, typename PelType> 
  bool getValue(const ImageType& image, PelPosition pos, PelType* pelValue);
```

In my calling code I have

```
getValue<LinearInterpolator>(image, pos, pelValue);
```

And I get the compiler error "missing template argument list". My question is: is what I am trying to do completely infeasible or am I missing something here.

Comment: please post more code. At least the interpolator interfaces and the definition of `getValue`.

Comment: Alexandre - It's the company's code and this is a simplified version. The skeleton looks like this: template<typename InterpType, typename ImageType, typename PelType> 
  bool getValue(const ImageType& image, PelPosition pos, PelType* pelValue) { InterpType<Imagetype> interpolator(image); *pelValue = interpolator.interpolate(pos); return true;}

Comment: @dln: ok. What you want to achieve does work. I was suspecting an error in another part of the code. Maybe are you missing a template argument list in a class template.

Comment: @dln: which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Alexandre: I had a version without using Interptype as the parameter. That worked just fine. The problem showed up when I added Interptype to the parameter list. But I will take a second look. I guess your message is that I CAN specify some parameters and let the compiler deduce the rest??

Comment: @dln: yep you can, provided the deduced parameters go after the mandatory ones. Deduced template arguments act like default template arguments.

Comment: Funny, with the given code and empty class and function bodies, VS2010 compiles just fine. The problem must be somewhere else it seems.

Comment: Perhaps one of the four classes is also a template and you are not specifying it's template list.

Comment: All, you are right. All interpolators are template classes. I should have read the error message more carefully.

Comment: @dln: Then post your own solution as an answer and accept it after two days. :)

Answer (score 0):

All right. The full class declaration for LinearInterpolator actually looks like this...

```
template <
  typename ImageType, 
  typename OutputPixelType = typename ImageType::Pixel, 
  typename FieldType = double, 
  template<typename From, typename To, typename Enable = void> class OutputPixelConverter = StaticCast
>
class LinearInterpolator : public AbstractInterpolator;
```

So I ended up taking the InterpType out of the type parameter list and passing in an enum as the parameter...

Old >>>>>

```
template<typename InterpType, typename ImageType, typename PelType> 
  bool getValue(const ImageType& image, PelPosition pos, PelType* pelValue);
```

New >>>>>

```
template<typename ImageType, typename PelType> 
  bool getValue(InterpType interp, const ImageType& image, PelPosition pos, PelType* pelValue);
```

If there is a better way of doing it, please comment.